# Espresso framework killed?

Tags: ruby

- all but latest gem versions yanked from rubygems
- [documentation sites](http://e.github.com) taken down
- source code is removed from github

Anyone who can point to future and status of framework?

Comment: https://github.com/mopo3ilo/espresso is online on github but is a year old. Have you tried to contact the author?

Comment: I think the original author has not responded to any contact. The above link is a mirror of the original.

Answer (score 1):

Seems nobody knows what exactly happened. There is similar question at Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/espresso-framework/toKzHfHFQkk

2 weeks ago I asked this question at StackOverflow and they down voted it to -3, because "it's not technical question".